# How to fix misaligned bootstrap columns when scroll bars are added

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a header and then a div that contains rows of similar information.
When the divs in the container fit without overflow they align fine.

See here: [Rows properly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jts9A.png)

But when there are more rows and the container adds a scroll bar (which I want it to do) on `overflow:auto` the rows lose alignment (my guess is because of the space that the scroll bar is taking)

See here: [Rows now unaligned to make space for scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Y4T.png)

I will attach the code I am using at the bottom.
Does anyone know a workaround that I can use so that everything will stay evenly aligned even when it overflows and adds the vertical scroll bars?  I am using bootstrap 4.6.

Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="orders" class="summary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Order #</div></div>
      <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Time</div></div>
      <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Name</div></div>
      <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Created By</div></div>
      <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Total</div></div>
      <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Sale</div></div>
      <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Status</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light" style='height:20%; overflow:auto;'>
    <div id='orders-container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Order #</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Time</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Name</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Created By</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Total</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Sale</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Status</div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Order #</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Time</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Name</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Created By</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Total</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Sale</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Status</div></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **javascript** to get the **[*offsetWidth*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)** of the `document.documentElement`, then you subtract the **[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)** of the second rows element which does not have the scroll bar included and this will give you your scroll bars width. Then place a class in the top row to set the `width` to a calculated measurement using view width units => `topEl.style.maxWidth = calc(100vw - ${scrollBarWidth})`

### JavaScript

```js
let sbWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - document.querySelectorAll('.row')[1].clientWidth;
const topEl = document.querySelector('.top')
topEl.style.width = `calc(100vw - ${sbWidth}px)`
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-light" style='height:20%; overflow:auto;'>
    <div id='orders-container'>
      <!--/ added class "top" to the first row /-->
      <div class="row top">
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Order #</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Time</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Name</div></div>
        <div class='col-2'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Created By</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Total</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Sale</div></div>
        <div class='col-1'><div class="col-12 h2 text-light font-weight-bold text-center bg-dark rounded pb-2 pt-2">Status</div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
```

Alternatively you could statically add the class to the first row and then add css for the class which would be somewhere between 12 to 18 pixels but this would not be as accurate.

```css
.top {
  width: calc(100vw - 17px);
}
```